# How to get inserted IDs of multiple rows on one INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to insert multiple rows into a table, using a single `INSERT` statement. This is no problem, since SQL offers the option to provide multiple rows as parameter for a single `INSERT` statement. Now, those rows contain an `ID` field that is incremented automatically, i.e. its value is set by the database, not by my code.

As a result, I would like to get the `ID` values of the inserted rows. My basic question is: How do I do that for MariaDB / MySQL?

As it turns out, this is pretty simple, e.g. in PostgreSQL, as PostgreSQL has the [`RETURNING` clause for `INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) which returns the desired values for one or even for multiple rows. This is exactly what I want and it works.

Unfortunately, neither MariaDB nor MySQL have PostgreSQL's `RETURNING` clause, so I need to fallback to something such as `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, but this only returns the `ID` of the single last inserted row, even if multiple rows were inserted using a single `INSERT`. How do I get all the `ID` values?

My code currently looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
  (foo, bar)
VALUES
  ('fooA', 'barA'),
  ('fooB', 'barB');

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id;
```

How can I solve this issue in a way that works even with concurrent writes?

(And no, it's not an option to change to a UUID field, or something like this; the auto-increment field is given, and can not be changed.)

Comment: `OUTPUT INSERTED.id` returns the `id`'s of ALL inserted rows, not just the last one.

Comment: This is all over the place. Which DBMS do you want an answer for? I can help with sql server but your statement there is incorrect. OUTPUT returns ALL values from the insert. That leads me to question how you are doing your insert. I think you need to decide which DBMS you are wanting an answer for and provide your insert statement.

Comment: Have you tried looping the rows in one by one and grabbing each id as you go using scope_identity()?

Comment: I need to solve this for MySQL, MariaDB, and SQL Server. Hence I didn't ask about one specific database, but for all of them. Regarding SQL Server and its `OUTPUT` clause – okay, I seem to have missed something here, I will have a look into this.

Comment: Well the answer is going to be different for each DBMS because they all handle this kind of thing a bit differently.

Comment: I've updated my question for MariaDB / MySQL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MySQL & MariaDB have the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function, and it returns the id generated by the most recent INSERT statement in your current session.

But when your INSERT statement inserts multiple rows, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the *first* id in the set generated.

In such a batch of multiple rows, you can rely on the subsequent id's being consecutive. The MySQL JDBC driver depends on this, for example.

If the rows you insert include a mix of NULL and non-NULL values for the id column, you have a risk of messing up this assumption. The JDBC driver returns the wrong values for the set of generated id's.

Comment: Important to further add that, on busy systems, it's possible for multiple queries to try to insert multiple rows at very nearly the same instant. In this situation, you should still be safe to assume consecutive inserts, because the database should use locking and transactions (implicit, if necessary) to make sure those queries don't step on each other's toes.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments, you can capture the inserted IDs (SQL Server):

```
use tempdb

create table test (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    t varchar(10) null
)

create table ids (
    i int not null
)

insert  test(t)
output  inserted.id into ids
values (null), (null), (null)


select  *
from    test

select  *
from    ids
```